# How to scrape the actual data from the website in headless mode chrome python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

opts = Options()
opts.set_headless()
assert opts.headless  # Operating in headless mode
browser = Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\taksh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\chromedriver.exe", options=opts)
browser.implicitly_wait(3)
browser.get('https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/quote/AMZN/profile?p=AMZN')

results = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="quote-header-info"]/div[3]/div/div/span[1]')
print(results)
```

And I get back:

```
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="b3f4e2760ffec62836828e62530f082e", element="3e2741ee-8e7e-4181-9b76-e3a731cefecf")>]
```

What I actually what selenium to scrape is the price of the stock. I thought i was doing it correctly because this would find the element when I used selenium on Chrome without headless mode. How can I scrape the actual data from the website in headless mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to further extract the data after getting all element in a list.

```
results = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="quote-header-info"]/div[3]/div/div/span[1]')

for result in results:
    print(result.text)
```

This will display all the data present in list.

Comment: I seeeee! So basically if I am using selenium with headlesss mode, any sort of data that I scrape I will have to write this for loop to display it basically correct?

Comment: @JackJones, exactly, you should do write a loop to extract data, no matter whether its GUI mode or headless.  `find_elements` returns list of webelement not list of string. `.text` is there to get individual web element text. in your case while you printing `results` its printing all weblement present in that list nothing else. If there is single element then go with `find_elements`

Comment: i see, so basically if for some reason you may get an error when trying to scrape the data, it isn't a bad idea to try find_element instead of find_elements because you might have multiple elements of that type correct?

Comment: If there is only one element then use `find_element` and if scrapping multiple same type of element then `find_elements`. If  element is not there while using `find_element` then it will throw NoSuchElementException while `find_elements` returns 0 in this case. So to avoid exception you can use  `find_elements` and check if size >0 the element there else no element. without facing the exception.

Answer (score 0):

It could be same xpath and locator appearing multiple time in html.
So
if we can put this code in try-catch while checking in headless mode.

Headless mode basically will scan HTML only so to debug better Try - differnt version of xpath like going to its parent of span and then traversing it